# Coherent sheaves of finite length

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, noetherian

Where can I find a treatment of *coherent sheaves of finite length* over, say, Noetherian schemes? Just things as basic as their definition and elementary facts about them. I am familiar with modules of finite length over a commutative ring and I think one can define coherent sheaves of finite length over schemes in a similar manner but I cannot find this notion anywhere and google search didn't help, either. Does anybody know a reference?

Comment: Essentially all properties of Artinian modules are true for your sheaves. Have you a specific question in mind ?

Comment: I need to work with the category of coherent sheaves of finite length over Noetherian schemes, in a work in progress, and I wanted to be able to reference to somewhere for the material on this. But here are some specific questions: (1) Can one define a coherent sheaf of finite length as a coherent sheaf whose support consists of a finite number of closed points? (2) A coherent sheaf of finite length can be placed at the end of chain of coherent subsheaves with successive quotients being *simple* sheaves? And the length of such a chain (ending with $0$) is the length of the sheaf?

Comment: (3) Suppose $\mathcal{F}$ is a coherent sheaf of finite length over a Noetherian scheme $X$. So this means support of $\mathcal{F}$ consists of a finite number of closed points. Do we have the following equality:
$$\operatorname{length}\mathcal{F}=\sum_{x\in X}\operatorname{length}_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}}\mathcal{F}_x?$$

Comment: Yes to all these questions. As a sheaf is a direct sum of sheaves supported at a single closed point. This is a rather simple exercise, and I doubt there is written reference.

Comment: Thank you for the response.